# R scatter plot with ellipse of boundaries using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I would like to plot this data with ellipses around the boundaries of
the categories I have divided. I have tried with different sample examples but I keep getting errors returned.

The description of the data looks as below. Can I get some suggestions for this type of data?

```
  result.bus result.sd category
1  0.4856291 0.9016849        1
2  0.5025360 0.8947358        1
3  0.5632551 0.9269805        1
4  0.5073693 0.9662483        1
5  0.5258539 0.8957916        1
6  0.5683056 0.9715885        1
```

[image: I would]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use can use the `stat_ellipse` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  stat_ellipse(geom="polygon", aes(fill = Species), 
                      alpha = 0.2,
                      show.legend = FALSE, 
                      level = 0.95)
```

[image]

For base R, you can use the scatterplot function from the **car** package.

```
library(car)

scatterplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, 
        ellipse=TRUE, regLine=FALSE, smooth=FALSE, data=iris)
```

[image]

The help pages offers some explanations:

`ellipse`

> Controls plotting data-concentration ellipses. If FALSE (the default),
> no ellipses are plotted. Can be a list of named values giving levels,
> a vector of one or more bivariate-normal probability-contour levels at
> which to plot the ellipses; robust, a logical value determining
> whether to use the cov.trob function in the MASS package to calculate
> the center and covariance matrix for the data ellipses; and fill and
> fill.alpha, which control whether the ellipse is filled and the
> transparency of the fill. TRUE is equivalent to list(levels=c(.5,
> .95), robust=TRUE, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.2).

Comment: Similar to what I want.... I have added my expected result in my edited question, but I would like the ellipses to form boundaries around the total values in the categories. I think the posted  image is a ellipse of 95% confidence interval

Comment: That looks like it was created using `autoplot` from a principal components analysis.