# How to insert ellipses with color opacity in groups?

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have this code:

```
library(echarts4r)

iris |> 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) |> 
  e_charts(Sepal.Length) |> 
  e_scatter(Petal.Length, symbol_size = 5) |>
  e_tooltip()
```

How to insert ellipses with color opacity in groups?

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what you exactly want. Is it the clusters and how do you want to define these clusters like using k-means?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stat_ellipse` function:

We can use  this example to perform a [Linear Discriminant Analysis in R](https://www.statology.org/linear-discriminant-analysis-in-r/), similar to yours and easy to reproduce with the [code here](https://github.com/Statology/R-Guides/blob/main/linear_discriminant_analysis).

Then, you can use `ggplot` and `stat_ellipse` function, [as already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62809348/15834162),

and to vary the opacity of the ellipse's color as you wish, you can change the `alpha` value, 1 for very opaque and 0 for transparent,

```
ggplot(lda_plot, aes(LD1, LD2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + 
  stat_ellipse(geom="polygon", aes(fill = Species), 
               alpha = 0.2,
               show.legend = FALSE, 
               level = 0.95) +
  ggtitle("a) Opacity 0.2")

ggplot(lda_plot, aes(LD1, LD2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + 
  stat_ellipse(geom="polygon", aes(fill = Species), 
               alpha = 0.8,
               show.legend = FALSE, 
               level = 0.95) +
  ggtitle("b) Opacity 0.8")
```

such as,
[image]

I hope I have answered your question